# How can i change the Text Color of items in Recycler View using a Toggle Button?

Tags: android

I am using a Switch to change the background and text colour of the Activity. But i don't under stand how can i change the text Colour of RecyclerView Items by toggling the switch
here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gagandeep.test;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SeekBar seekBar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ItemAdapter adapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Switch switchToggle;
    TextView head;
    ConstraintLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        findViews();
        click();



    }

    private void findViews() {
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.constraint);
        head = findViewById(R.id.head);
    }

    private void click() {
        seekBar.setMax(20);
        seekBar.setProgress(10);
        timeTable(10);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Multiplying a number by 0 always gives zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    seekBar.setProgress(1);
                    timeTable(1);
                }
                else
                    timeTable(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void timeTable(int progress) {
        ArrayList<Item> table = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<=20; i++){
            table.add(new Item(i + " * " + progress + " = " + i*progress ));
        }
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, table);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        switchToggle = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch)
                .getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchAB);

        switchToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checked();
                }
                if (!isChecked){
                    unChecked();
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private void unChecked() {
        layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }

    private void checked() {
        layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.myswitch:

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

here is my ItemAdapter.java

```
package com.example.gagandeep.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> list;
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item currentItem = list.get(position);
        holder.head.setText(currentItem.getHead());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView head;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            head = itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);
        }
    }
}
```

Where do i have to make the changes so i can change the textColor at runtime?

Comment: you can achieve this in two ways. 1 by adding style to all edit text and on toggle change style for all text at the activity level. 2.) pass value from activity to adapter and in onBindViewHolder change the color of textView and call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Do you want to change the color of a single item in your RecyclerView or all of the items ?